# How to use dependent drop down list using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on AngularJS. I'm trying to  use the drop down list in  dependent manner but in  my second drop down list i'm  getting undefined as the data after i select the first drop down. Please can any one help  me from  this ?

```
Here is my Html :

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>

     <div ng-app="Aplic" ng-controller="CountryCntrl">
        <select name="country" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.productGroup as country.productGroup for country  in countries">
            <option value="">Choose</option>
        </select>

        Departement:
        <select name="state" 
        ng-model="selectedCountry"
        ng-options="state.productGroup as state.productCode for state in ((countries | filter:{'productCode':selectedCountry})[0].productGroup) track by state.productCode">
            <option value="">Choose</option>
        </select>
    </div>

      </body>

    </html>


And my  script :



// Code goes here

 var Aplic = angular.module("Aplic", []);

 Aplic.controller('CountryCntrl', function ($scope) {

     $scope.countries =
   [
  {
    "productCode": "PRD2_SBBD",
    "productGroup": "SBBD"
  },

  {
    "productCode": "SBM_WDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },

  {
    "productCode": "SMP_WDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_BA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_BA_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "UN_SBML",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_UB_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_UB_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_AC_HP1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_MLAC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_MLAC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_AC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_LOW_LTV",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_AC_LTV",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_AC_LTV",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },

  {
    "productCode": "MUL",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  }
  ];
 });
```

And let me show you  the plunker  for reference:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Jh3SyewxbvbubnK1W6GY?p=preview.

Comment: Is it possible to change the JSON data? I think the structure could be optimized.

Comment: @ jlast Nope , we are  not  suppose  to  change the json

Answer (score 2):

Here you go (*Just click `Run code snippet` below*):

```js
// Code goes here

 var Aplic = angular.module("Aplic", []);

 Aplic.controller('CountryCntrl', function ($scope) {
    
     $scope.countries =
   [
  {
    "productCode": "PRD2_SBBD",
    "productGroup": "SBBD"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PRD4_SBBD",
    "productGroup": "SBBD"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PRD1_SBBD",
    "productGroup": "SBBD"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PRD3_SBBD",
    "productGroup": "SBBD"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PRD_SBBD",
    "productGroup": "SBBD "
  },
  {
    "productCode": "EF_L3",
    "productGroup": "EF"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "EF_L4",
    "productGroup": "EF"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "EF_L5",
    "productGroup": "EF"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "EF_L1",
    "productGroup": "EF"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "EF_L2",
    "productGroup": "EF"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_UB_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_L5",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_L6",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_L4",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_L7",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_UB_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "PPC_UB_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHL_BA_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHL_BA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHL_WCDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SHL_WDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHL_WCDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SHL_WDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHA_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHL_AL_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHL_AL_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHP_BA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHP_BA_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHP_BA_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHPA_BA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHPA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHPA_BA_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHPA_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHPA_WCDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SHPA_WDC_2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHPA_WCDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SHPA_WDC_1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHP_WCDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SHP_WDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHP_WCDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SHP_WDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "UN_SBHL",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHP_AC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHP_AC_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBHP_AC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_BA_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_BA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_BA_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_BA_L4",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_WCDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SML_WDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_WCDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBM_WDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_WCDC_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBM_WDC_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_WCDC_L4",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBM_WDC_L4",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMA_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMLA_BA_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMLA_BA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMLA_WCDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SMLA_WDC_2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMLA_WCDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SMLA_WDC_1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_AC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_LOW_LTV",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBM_LO_LTV",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_AC_LT",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_BA_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_UB_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_UB_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_UB_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_UB_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_WCDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SMP_WDC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_WCDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SMP_WDC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_BA_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBMP_BA_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "UN_SBML",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_UB_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "SBML_UB_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "ML_AC_TN_1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "ML_AC_TN_2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "TP_SBHL_BA",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBML_L5",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBML_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBHL_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_AC_HP2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_AC_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_AC_HP3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_MLAC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_MLAC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_AC_HP1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_MLAC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_MLAC_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_AC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_LOW_LTV",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_AC_LTV",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_AC_LTV",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_AC_HP3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_AC_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_AC_HP2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_AC_HP1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_LOW_LTV",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBML_L5",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBML_L6",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBML_L7",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBML_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBML_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBML_L4",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBHP_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBML_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBHP_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VT_SBHP_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBML_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBHP_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBML_L6",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBML_L7",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBML_L2",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBHP_L1",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBML_L4",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "VK_SBHP_L3",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "B1L",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "B1S",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "B2L",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "B2S",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "H1L",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "H1S",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "H2L",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "H2S",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "M1H",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "M1L",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "M1M",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "M2L",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "M2M",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "MHL",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "MHS",
    "productGroup": "SBHL"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "MSL",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "MSS",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "MUL",
    "productGroup": "SBML"
  }
  ];
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
 <div ng-app="Aplic" ng-controller="CountryCntrl">
    <select name="country" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.productGroup as country.productGroup for country  in countries">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
    </select>
    
    Departement:
    <select name="state" 
    ng-model="selectedState"
    ng-options="state.productGroup as state.productCode for state in countries | filter:{'productGroup':selectedCountry} track by state.productCode">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
    </select>
</div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @ Aruna its perfect  but why  is it not working in  my  local

Comment: Don't forget to add the links to the js and css files? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` and `<script src="script.js"></script>`. Its missing in the above snippet. I have updated your plunker link, http://plnkr.co/edit/irUqK6bkAsuKyRO9ZMc2?p=preview

Comment: @ Aruna nope i  have added  the links but its not working in  my  local

Comment: Whatever you tried, can you update the same by editing your question or in the plunker?

Comment: @ Aruna <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Product : </label>
                  <select id="Select" class="form-control" name="productGroup" ng-model="query.productGroup" ng-options="product.productGroup as product.productCode for product in products | filter:{'productGroup':query.productGroup} track by product.productCode">
                    <option value="">Select Product</option>
                  </select>

                </div>

Comment: Post html for both select?

Comment: @ Aruna i'm  getting the data in  drop down list  but not able to  select  it  .

Comment: I know why it is, Can you Post the html for both select? The above has just one select

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Product Group:<i class="mandate">*</i></label>
                  <select id="Select" class="form-control" name="productGroup" ng-model="query.productGroup" ng-options="product.productGroup as product.productGroup for product in products | unique: 'productGroup'| orderBy:'productGroup'">

                    <option value="">Select Product Group</option>
                  </select>
                  <span class="error" ng-show="search_form.productGroup.$error.required">Product Group is required</span>
                </div>

Comment: @ Aruna i have sent you  both the select

Comment: Both select has the same model `ng-model="query.productGroup"`. That's the issue which should be having the same. Change the second select model ("product") as `ng-model="query.product"`

Comment: @ Aruna still facing the same issue ,  is that because i'm  using the API data ?

Comment: Can you explain what happens? Did you get data in first select?

Comment: @ Aruna i'm  getting  the data , no  problem in that  , but  i'm  not able to  select  the drop down in  the Product field .

Comment: Can you able to select the product group? If so, can you post the updated (latest) html for the product select?

Comment: @ Yes i'm  able to  select  the Product group.  </select>
                    <select id="Select" class="form-control" name="productGroup" ng-model="query.product" ng-options="product.productGroup as product.productCode for product in products | filter:{'productGroup':query.product} track by product.productCode">
                    <option value="">Select Product</option>
                  </select>

Comment: You should not change the filter. Change this to `filter:{'productGroup':query.productGroup}`. I have asked you to change the `ng-model` only.

Answer (score 0):

state.productGroup as state.productCode for state in (**(countries | filter:{'productCode':selectedCountry})**) track by state.productCode